# Why will Threads.@spawn and Threads.@threads execute for different time?

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, julia

I saw a post from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61905127/what-is-the-difference-between-threads-spawn-and-threads-threads)

I do not know why `withthreads()` needs more time than `withsync()`.

```
function withthreads()
    arr = zeros(Int, 10)
    Threads.@threads for i in 1:10
       # sleep(3 * rand())
       sleep(1)
       arr[i] = i
    end
    println("with @threads: $arr")
end

function withsync()
    arr = zeros(Int, 10)
    @sync begin
        for i in 1:10
           Threads.@spawn begin
               # sleep(3 * rand())
               sleep(1)
               arr[i] = i
           end
        end
    end
    println("with @sync: $arr")
end

@time withthreads()
@time withsync()
```

I execute the script by `julia -t4 test.jl` and following is the output:

```
with @threads: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
  3.174835 seconds (18.51 k allocations: 1.072 MiB, 2.52% compilation time)
with @sync: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
  1.035465 seconds (1.40 k allocations: 75.718 KiB, 1.28% compilation time)
```

I expected they would need the same time.

Answer (score 1):

The julia command line option `-t 4` or `--threads=4` specifies the number of *processor threads* within the julia process.

The julia macro `Threads.@threads` divides work among the available threads.

The julia macro `@spawn` creates a *task*.  Tasks are scheduled to run on a processor thread when available.  `@sync` waits for the spawned tasks to complete.

`withsync` is creating 10 separate tasks, one for each index i.  So when one of the 4 processor threads reaches the `sleep` statement in one task, there may be other tasks to which it can switch and make progress.

`withthreads` divides the work into only 4 tasks, one for each of the 4 threads available.  Conceptually, it does something similar to this code, described below:

```
function withsyncblocks()
    local arr = zeros(Int, 10)
    local range = 1:10
    local lenrange = length(range)
    local nthreads = Threads.threadpoolsize()   # = Threads.nthreads() if 1 threadpool
    local lenblock = cld(lenrange, nthreads)    # ceiling division
    @sync begin
        for blocknumber in 1:nthreads
           Threads.@spawn begin
               local f = Threads.firstindex(range) + (blocknumber - 1) * lenblock
               local l = min(f + lenblock - 1, lenrange)
               for i in f:l
                   # sleep(3 * rand())
                   sleep(1)
                   arr[i] = i
               end
            end
         end
    end
    println("with @sync blocks: $arr")
end

@time withsyncblocks()
```

Since there are fewer processor threads than iterations, it divides the work into blocks of iterations, with multiple iterations per block.  It spawns one task for each block.  In each block, the later iterations are performed after the earlier iterations complete, which means waiting for each `sleep`.  Because there are only 4 tasks and 4 processor threads, there are no other tasks to which a processor thread can switch while its current task waits for a `sleep`.  So the thread contributes no further progress while the task is sleeping.

---

Threads.@threads chooses a block size that tries to evenly divide the iterations between threads.  Choosing a smaller block size would create more tasks, but adds overhead in time and memory to create more tasks and switch between them.  If the work does not involving waiting for sleep or input/output devices or networks, then creating more tasks than processor threads can produce overhead that slows down the computation.

You could try setting `-t 10` to make @threads divide the work into 10 blocks.
This program does wait, for `sleep`, so dividing iterations into one iteration per task can speed it up.

Typically the number of processor threads is set to the number of physical cores that can share the memory of the julia process within a CPU.  Or if the task is memory bound, it can be set to the number of logical cores. (Each physical core with SMT simultaneous multithreading hardware may implement a small number of logical cores, typically 2.  Each such physical core can keep the state of a small number of threads in separate logical core registers and quickly switch between them while waiting for a memory fetch.)

Comment: Perfect answer! I want to add a small question: Looks that `@spawn` could obtain the same goal as `@threads` by less allocations and less physical cores and less elapsed time. So when is the `@threads` better than `@spawn`?

Comment: Perhaps a weakness of using @time is that it includes the compilation overhead, and @threads is a more complex macro.   Try commenting out the `sleep` statements, and   `using BenchmarkTools`, then `@btime withthreads()`, then `@btime withsync()`.